# trying to read HornetQ bodyBuffer and getting NegativeArraySizeException

Tags: hornetq

trying to use

```
val nullablestr = hornetQMessage.getBodyBuffer.readNullableSimpleString.toString
```

or

```
val strMessage = hornetQMessage.getBodyBuffer.readString
```

getting

> java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
>     at org.hornetq.core.buffers.impl.ChannelBufferWrapper.readSimpleStringInternal(ChannelBufferWrapper.java:83)
>     at org.hornetq.core.buffers.impl.ChannelBufferWrapper.readNullableSimpleString(ChannelBufferWrapper.java:58)
>     at com.gamescale.messaging.hornetQ.HornetQMessageConverter$.extractGSMessage(HornetQMessageConverter.scala:68)
>     at com.gamescale.messaging.hornetQ.MessageBusHornetQClientImpl$$anonfun$1$$anon$2$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(MessageBusHornetQClientImpl.scala:246)
>     at com.gamescale.messaging.hornetQ.MessageBusHornetQClientImpl$$anonfun$1$$anon$2$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(MessageBusHornetQClientImpl.scala:243)
>     at akka.actor.Actor$class.apply(Actor.scala:563)
>     at com.gamescale.messaging.hornetQ.MessageBusHornetQClientImpl$$anonfun$1$$anon$2.apply(MessageBusHornetQClientImpl.scala:242)
>     at akka.actor.LocalActorRef.invoke(ActorRef.scala:905)
>     at akka.dispatch.MessageInvocation.invoke(MessageHandling.scala:25)
>     at akka.dispatch.ExecutableMailbox$class.processMailbox(ExecutorBasedEventDrivenDispatcher.scala:216)
>     at akka.dispatch.ExecutorBasedEventDrivenDispatcher$$anon$4.processMailbox(ExecutorBasedEventDrivenDispatcher.scala:122)
>     at akka.dispatch.ExecutableMailbox$class.run(ExecutorBasedEventDrivenDispatcher.scala:188)
>     at akka.dispatch.ExecutorBasedEventDrivenDispatcher$$anon$4.run(ExecutorBasedEventDrivenDispatcher.scala:122)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>     at akka.dispatch.MonitorableThread.run(ThreadPoolBuilder.scala:184)

I am using the same method to write the message

`hornetQMessage.getBodyBuffer.writeString(message)`

any ideas ?

Comment: Which HornetQ version is this? Also, you should mention the HQ server and client versions, or at least confirm that all actors are using the same version. Fwiw, most of your stack trace is unrelated to HQ and -as I see it- unrelated to the question, you should trim that.

Answer (score 1):

As a reference to any HornetQ users. The [cause of this bug was determined at the HornetQ forum](https://community.jboss.org/message/822493#822493).

In short, it was caused by reading values from the buffer in the wrong order. Say, you write a negative integer before writing the string, then at the other side, you try to read the string without reading the negative integer first.